# Angular routing in a sub-folder not working

Tags: angular

I am deploying an Angular App in a sub-folder. Landing page works fine. But other routers are not working. Showing 404 error.

For Ex:

```
www.xxx.com/demo -> Loads landing page.

www.xxx.com/demo/about -> Showing 404 error.
```

I have tried below commands to build application.

```
ng build --prod --base-href /demo/

ng build --prod --base-href /demo/ --deploy-url /demo/
```

I have hosted my application [here](https://debabratapatra.github.io/pages/ngtreegrid/demo/).

Am I missing something?

Comment: do you need to change you base href?

Comment: I think Yes, Otherwise all scripts will be tried to load from www.xxx.com not from www.xxx.com/demo.

Comment: your server isn't serving `index.html` for every call beyond the angular route. it doesn't "allow angular to handle" the routes. My guess is, adding `useHash: true` to the routes import, would solve it. `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})]`. This would add a `#` and make sure the routing stays client-side.

Comment: Couple of questions—1) I assume your build command you described is same way you actually put. Can you view source the page and see what your base href is pointing?  2) is this happening while you route or when you reload the page?

Comment: @Stavm thanks for your response. It worked. https://debabratapatra.github.io/pages/angular-tree-grid/demo/#/basic_tree_grid. I am using github. I don't think I have control over it's server.

Comment: @Subhajit 1)  base href points to correct path in view source. You can see https://debabratapatra.github.io/pages/ngtreegrid/demo/ here. 2) Both. Thanks.

Comment: @DebabrataPatra adding as an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that your server is not serving `index.html` for every call beyond the angular route, so it doesn't "allow angular to handle" the route change.

I guess, adding `useHash: true` to the routes import, would solve it.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})]
})
```

This will add a hash (`#`) to your urls, making sure the routing stays client-side.